# Issues with HashMap with Integer as key

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi I having issues with `HashMap` with `Integer` as key.

I am getting inconsistent results  when I using  `Integer` as the key for my map.

I read few posts which suggests that ,If I am using `Integer` as key in `Hashmap`,  I need to make sure that both override and `hashcode` methods of `Integer` class are overridden. In the Integer class, method `equals()` is already overridden. Now how do I override the `equals()` method.

Comment: can you give an example of the inconsistent results you are encountering?

Comment: I've posted an answer of one potential problem, but I also agree with other commentators that you haven't really explained, with sample code, exactly what problem you're actually having.

Answer (score 5):

There's no problem in principle with using Integers as the key to a HashMap.

However, a subtle issue is that number **wrappers of different classes containing the same numeric value don't match** as far as a call to equals() is concerned.

So for example, if I do this:

```
map.put(3, "Test")
```

and then try and retrieve the value like this:

```
long x = 1;
map.get(x + 2)
```

the original value will not be found. If you rely on autoboxing without thinking about things, you can occasionally run into this problem.

Comment: How can this be possible? `map.get(x+2)` should do the same thing as `map.get(3)`. The expression will get evaluated first and only then converted to Integer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

`java.lang.Integer` already overrides both [`equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.hashCode%28%29), like any value type provided in the built-in libraries.  You don't need to do anything.

Comment: thanks , I am not sure why I am getting inconsisten results. This only happens if the int value of key is more than 40                                                                flowSession.getInterviewAnswers().put(Integer.parseInt(43), listOfInterviewAnswers);  It sometimes save the result at 42nd location in the table. and this entry get overwritten when actual 42nd value is passed

Comment: @user1792972 This is a wild guess but are you using `==` to compare `Integer`s anywhere in your code?

Comment: @user1792972 - Well unless you post your code, we can only guess.